# xslt PDF transformation in .NET 5.0: problem with special character

Tags: c#, pdf, xslt

I have a problem with special "exotic" characters when doing XSLT transformation to PDF. This is my code in C# :

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("myXml.xml");
XDocument xslt = XDocument.Load("myXSL.xsl");
XsltArgumentList args = new XsltArgumentList();

string str = XmlLinqXsltExtensions.Transform(xmlDoc, xslt, args);
File.WriteAllText("foStr.xml",str);

XslFOPdfOptions xslFoPdfOptions = new XslFOPdfOptions();
xslFoPdfOptions.EnablePrinting = true;

FONetXslFOPdfRenderer foNetXslFoPdfRenderer = new FONetXslFOPdfRenderer(XDocument.Load(("foStr.xml"), xslFoPdfOptions);
byte[] bytes = foNetXslFoPdfRenderer.RenderPdfBytes();
outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);      // bytes contain the PDF
```

The "myXml.xml" is in UTF-8. It contains some special characters as "ć" and others:

[image]

The Stylesheet "myXSL.xsl" does have the information for encoding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
```

The output of the intermediate "foStr.xml" is correct:

[image]

And the "foStr.xml" encoding is UTF-8, too.

Nevertheless in the PDF, I get the replace char # in the output:

#ebi-Ili# #nn#

**Question:**

Any idea how to make the FONetXslFOPdfRenderer to produce the correct chararcters?

Version of the nuget packages:

- PdfTemplating.XslFO.Common:    2.1.0
- PdfTemplating.XslFO.Xslt:    2.0.0

Comment: What does the code `string str = XmlLinqXsltExtensions.Transform(xmlDoc, xslt, args);` do exactly? Does the string `str` carry an XML declaration with an encoding declared at the beginning? Is `File.WriteAllText("foStr.xml",str);` ensuring that the file is written with the declared encoding?

Comment: We really need to see the code of your method `XmlLinqXsltExtensions.Transform`. My guess is there is a mismatch between the encoding the string carries it returns and the default UTF-8 encoding the `File.WriteAllText` method uses. That way the `XDocument.Load(("foStr.xml")` then fails to properly decode characters.

Comment: The string "str" contains the fo-data which you need as input to produce the PDF. It also has the encoding mark at the beginning: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fo:root .....
And the file is detected to be UTF-8 by my texteditor.

Comment: XmlLinqXsltExtensions is part of the NuGet package PdfTemplating.XslFO.Xslt .

Comment: So it looks more like a font setting problem for that PDF renderer. No idea how that is done for that package, see whether you can find some options to ensure it uses a font that can render the non-ASCII characters.

Comment: As already said in the initial question, the data in foStr.xml seems to be in UTF-8. The characters are displayed correctly there.

Comment: I also had the idea of a setting problem for the PDF renderer. But I couldn't find any suitable setting option.

Comment: There seems to be an option to do the XSL-FO to PDF generation trough an Azure Function using the latest Apache FOP, perhaps try whether that way you get a better result.

Comment: Other things you could try is to have the XSL-FO specify a font that has good support for non-ASCII characters and is available on the platform where you run the code.

Comment: Does `<fo:block font-family="Arial">ć</fo:block>` render fine?

Comment: Oh! Nice.... this one works!

Comment: Just manipulated the foStr.xml during debugging. - Well, then let's get it to work in the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After Martin Honnen proposal for font-family="Arial", the answer is in fact to choose a font family for which the support of special characters is big enough.

You can do e.g. this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xsl:use-attribute-sets="text-attributes">
...
```

and

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="text-attributes">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-family">Arial</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

which would be a general solution to the problem.